# unable to upload doc files in android latest version

Tags: files

I am not able to upload  .doc files on my android mobile.I have Kingston software installed so whenever I use the upload button from the webpage it just displays my gallery, camera, voice and video recorder. It does not display the file browser so that I can select the file from my file system.

Comment: Please consider that we don't all have exactly the same software as you, so we don't necessarily know what this "Kingston software" is you mention, nor what webpage you're talking about. To get better answers, [edit] your question to describe the problem more fully, and include your phone and Android version.

Comment: This is a genuine question. I just did a factory reset on my Android 4.2.2 and there is no Kingston software. But when I try to attach a file in Gmail, I am not given an option to choose a file from the filesystem. Even trying to attach a file from Google Drive doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By installing androZip my problem is getting resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the software you're using but I'd recommend looking into [Airdroid](http://airdroid.com/), it installs a small application on your phone and lets you manage it from a web interface. After starting the service you can copy all data in both directions.

Comment: And how does that help uploading files to a website? Airdroid is to remotely manage your Android device, which is a completely different task.

Comment: "Kingston" is similar to MS Office where you can edit/modify doc, xl, pdf and view presentations. I have read similar issues I am hearing about EStrong File Explorer and androZip. Are they helpful software ? can resolve my issue ??.

Comment: that might be right Izzy and is now clear when I know that Kingston seems to be some kind of office suite.
@RizwanSA So what "webpage" are you trying to upload your files to?